# <List> Sort help C# (unity)

Tags: c#, list, sorting, unity-game-engine, sql-order-by

i need help sorting a List I have....

I have this list

```
List<List<string>> PlayerList= new List<List<string>>();
```

After being populated I'll have something like

```
[123112412,John,225,123.5522,Dalas]
[123312,Fred,12,43.5522,Chicago]
```

I can access then for example like:

```
PlayerList[0][1] = John
PlayerList[1][1] = Fred
```

Now the question... I Need to sort this "PlayerList" by the 4th field ... how can I do that... I'm really lost with C#.

I need the output to be something like:

```
[123312,Fred,12,43.5522,Chicago]
[123112412,John,225,123.5522,Dalas]
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I think the sorted list will be `sorted = PlayerList.OrderBy(list=>list[4]).ToList();`

Comment: No need to include C# / Unity in your title as you have them as tags

Comment: Sorry, first question here ...

Comment: Don't forget that you can define your own data structures. That `List<List<string>>` could just as easily be a `List<MyCustomClass>`. Which is clearer: `PlayerList[0][1]` or `PlayerList[0].name`?

Comment: Nice... I'll try also that.... tks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var newList = PlayerList.OrderBy(x => x[4]).ToList();


foreach (var line in newList)
{
    Console.WriteLine(string.Join(",", line));
}
```

Comment: and how do i cast, or say it is a number this field ?


Because its sorting as a string....

Comment: @FlavioEngel your 4th field is *string (Chicago/Dalas)*

Comment: @FlavioEngel **var newList = PlayerList.OrderBy(x => double.Parse(x[3],CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)).ToList();**

Comment: Thanks a lot L.B., C# still very new to me... In ActionScript this sort is so easy lol...